# Ubuntu One not syncing

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am really starting to despair as I have been trying Ubuntu One for several months, trying it on several machines, and it has caused me loads of different issues wasting me a lot of time. It is not straight forward to use, it should be a piece of software that runs in background and users should not think about checking all the time if it is really doing it's job.

Of course I have been searching around this website and other forums but couldn't find an answer to my situation.

Yesterday I had several problems with the client not syncing and using a lot of the machine's RAM, up and CPU. I had to reboot on several occasions and leave the office's PC on overnight in order to sync a few files of not more than a few MB.

1. Today I am experiencing another problem: I have decided to do a test putting a small file in my ubuntu one shared folder. Ubuntu one is not detecting it (now already more than an hour), therefore not uploading it to the server.

   ```
   martin@ubuntu-desktop:~$ u1sdtool --status
   State: QUEUE_MANAGER
   connection: With User With Network
   description: processing the commands pool
   is_connected: True
   is_error: False
   is_online: True
   queues: IDLE
   ```

   and

   ```
   martin@ubuntu-desktop:~$ u1sdtool --current-transfers
   Current uploads: 0
   Current downloads: 0
   ```

   I am running Ubuntu 11.04 64 with all recent updates.
2. On my other machine the transfer of files seems to be completely frozen, with around 10 files in the queue but no transfer whatsoever.
3. Another curious issue is on my Ubuntu 10.10 laptop where Ubuntu One seems to have completely disappeared from Nautilus context menu, folder/file sync status icons missing. I have therefore been forced to upgrade to 11.04 on this machine.

Anyway, now I would like to solve the **processing the commands pool** issue and make sure the client

Comment: try to check the extension..it just happened to me now..I found out the file that are being refused to be uploaded has the extension: u1conflict. Delete it by renaming the file and it will get uploaded

Answer (score 9):

ok, I have solved issue 1. by running the lines

```
u1sdtool --quit
u1sdtool --connect
u1sdtool --refresh-shares
```

and it started working right away
I still think that the client should be able to solve these problems by itself
ubuntuone should be more responsive, I am surprised that it has more problems than a third party service such as dropbox

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and added `u1sdtool --start` to start programms.

Answer (score 0):

I had syncing problem too, but as soon as I unlocked the key ring (which usually I just ignore) the syncing process started.