# Ubuntu one will not upload files - why?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I recently noticed my ubuntu one files stopped to be synched. I guess it has something to do with me buying a new disk, copying things over there and leaving them on ubuntu one meanwhile, because I think it stopped syncing just after me buying the new disk.

However, I tried ["File Sync error." with Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42065/file-sync-error-with-ubuntu-one) in order to reset my ubuntu one connection, but now I created folder with two (empty) files in it. The folder gets uploaded to Ubuntu one but the files do not (subfolders do not get uploaded either). Now u1sdtool -s gives this:

```
drew@steve:~$ u1sdtool -s
State: QUEUE_MANAGER
connection: With User With Network
description: processing the commands pool
is_connected: True
is_error: False
is_online: True
queues: IDLE
```

Ubuntu control center says synchronization is complete, but it is not. Any ideas? This used to work fine.

(byt the way - on two folders that stopped to be synced, the emblem green check is still displayed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ubuntu One not syncing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63211/ubuntu-one-not-syncing) helped (i.e. do

```
u1sdtool --quit
u1sdtool --connect
u1sdtool --refresh-shares
```

and then I had to disconnect and connect through Ubuntu control center (the thing that will get launched via messaging menu) and now files are uploading, I hope all get uploaded:-).